# Muhammad Infront of name confusion

Tags: practical-islam, muslim-practices, names

It is said that it is regarded as a best practice to name child Muhammad (name), but in western countries where first name is on your passport e.g Muhammad Ajmal Khan, whereas Ajmal is real first name but as on ID card or passport will make Muhammad name first, is it ok to leave Muhammad name out of name to end this confusion? Or is there anything like prefix that you mention on birth certificate? Today I had a baby boy and I am confused over naming convention.

Comment: بارك الله لك في الموهوب لك ،وشكرت الواهب، وبلغ أشدهُ، ورزقت برهُBaraka Allahu laka fi-l-Mawhoobi lak wa shakarta-l-Wahib wa balagha ashuda wa ruziqta birrah! The most preferable names are those who include "Hamd", like Ahmed, Hamid, Hammad or any name with "Abd" like Abullah, Abdul-rahman ... , but any other name is ok!

Answer (score 1):

Who said he has to be named Muhammed? You can name him anything, but it has to be a good name that doesn't represent anything bad. And having a prefix isn't necessary, it is rather a culture. And the best names are the names which start with Abdul (e.g Abdullah, Abdul Rahman, Abdul Latif, Abdul Aziz etc.)

Read this http://www.islamcan.com/names/names-that-are-preferred-and-that-are-undesirable..shtml#.VlagUnOwrqA It talks about this matter in detail.